# Wrap comment replies in a collapsible fieldset

Tags: 7, comments

I found an article about wrapping all comments (http://scito.ch/content/wrap-comments-collapsible-fieldset), but I just want to wrap comment replies in a collapsible fieldset.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)() and add the collapsible fieldset to the form field.  For example:

```
function MODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //Create the fieldset
    $form['custom_fieldset'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('My Collapsible Fieldset'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );

    //Move the field into the fieldset
    $form['custom_fieldset']['comment_body'] = $form['comment_body'];

    //Unset the original field
    unset($form['comment_body']);
}
```

You can set `'#collapsed' => TRUE` if you want the fieldset to be closed by default.

---

If you're looking for a Module based approach, you may want to look into the [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) project.

I'm not sure how well this module will get along with the Comment module though.  You may need to implement hook_form_alter() in a custom module or in your theme.

Comment: $form['comment_body'] contain my custom define field,so how can i just warp comment reply?

Comment: Ah, I may have misunderstood your question.  Are you wrapping the actual comments or the reply entry field?

Comment: just the reply entry field.because if many people post a comment reply in the same comment,the comment reply list so long so i want to collapse it

Comment: WIll you add your custom defined code to your question? I think I need to see it to move forward. :)

Comment: i use orginal drupal 7.14 with comment module and zen template.and also install ideal comment.i have not custom defined some code.Thank you again.