# Collapsible Search Bar

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I have an exposed form (from a view) in a block. I'd like to make this block collapsible so that a user is presented with a search box and one other field and when a user types in the search box the form expands out to include the remainder of the form fields. I know I can use ctools_collapsible to make content collapsible but how do I extend this to any div/region?

Comment: ctools_collapsible uses a hard coded HTML fragment to generate its div. You _might_ be able to pass like `drupal_get_form('search_form');` to it to embed your search form in a collapsible div. Or, you could hook_form_alter the the search block and include the jqueryui form elements for D7 and wrap your search form in a collapisble div, there is already an example of this here on stackexchange, like http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36387/wrap-comments-reply-in-a-collapsible-fieldset-drupal-7

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly:
You have exposed filter in block, which have for example two fields, search by title and checkboxes.

So you can use: https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters

1. After installing module: change **Exposed form style** from **Basic** to **Better Exposed Filters**
2. Click to **BEF Settings**
3. Check **Enable secondary exposed form options**
4. Expand yours fields what you need to hide before type in search box and check this: **This is a secondary option**
5. Use jQuery:

   ```
   $("input.yourSearchBox").keyup(function(){

       $(".views-widget-filter-secondary a").trigger('click');

   });
   ```